# The constructor for contracts/Greeter.sol: Greeter has 1 parameters but 0 arguments were provided instead

Tags: hardhat-deploy

There is an argument missing!

I understand that there is a parameter in the constructor "constructor(string memory _greeting)"

But I don't know where or what is the argument that I'm missing and where to put it to verify my contract on etherscan through hardhat plugin.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have another `contract.deploy()` function, check it out if there is anything wrong.

If you don't, delete `./artifacts` and `./cache` then try again.